# IdeaVIM Keybindings not working in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

I just upgraded IdeaVIM to use the newly added support for window management.  The problem I'm having is that the keybindings aren't working at all.  I've tried editing the keymap manually, adding back the default bindings, but they're not in effect.

When I hit C-w I get some help in the modeline letting me know which keybindings are available at that prefix (l for window right, h for window left etc) but when I hit the second key nothing happens!What's going on here?  I'm running ideavim 13.1.3.

Comment: What version of IdeaVim are you using? 13.1.3 is likely the version of IntelliJ IDEA. Have you set your keymap in Settings | Keymap? Does your ~/.ideavimrc contain any custom key mappings?

Comment: Latest version of ideavim, I have the following bindings in my `.ideavimrc`: `:map <C-e> $`
`:map <C-a> ^`
`:imap <C-e> <Esc>$la`
`:imap <C-a> <Esc>^i` I ended up just wiping all  my custom keybindings, to get the defaults to work again.  And I've just accepted that I can't edit the keybindings with `C-w` prefix.

Comment: Check that `<C-w>` is handled by the Vim emulation, not the IDE in Settings | Vim Emulation | Conflicts.

Comment: `C-w` isn't in the list at all.

Answer (score 9):

**NOT exactly** the same problem but for me
Vimidea / Vim plugin was not working on Pycharm / Rubymine / Intellij

**Finally found the solution!!!**
**(ON MAC)**

Just make sure that you don't have a conflict with the Keymap to refactor->extract->variable and vim emulator!

Go to settings->Keymap->MainMenu->Refactor->Extract->Variable
And remove the shortcut

Now run the shortcut to make the VimEmulator to run, in Mac just hit:

Cmd+option+V (option is the key next to command)

If its still doesn't work it means that you cannot exit insert mode - make sure to bind the escape key to:

settings->Keymap->Plug-ins->ideavim->Exit Insert Mode  == escape

**Actually** using the shortcut to start/stop VimEmulator is a great idea when you ask your team-mate help with your code and he/she is not used to working with Vim.

Just hit cmd+option+V and you are back to using the idea without Vim and again to start working with Vim again :)

Comment: yes, working on Mac. I don't know what it was, but I uninstalled the Material theme plugin and restarted, and then was able to ``shift-cmd-A``, and I turned Vim bindings on. Prior to doing that, I was not able.

Comment: Great! So I believe the steps above worked after all :) 
Happy to hear that it's working for you!

Comment: no. I had to uninstall the Material theme first. FYI - I un clicked the downvote per your request.

Answer (score 3):

You can enable/disble it through: shift-cmd-A, then type ideavim and you'll see a switch on there